# FragmentTabHost onChoose Tab onActivityCreate Again

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment-tab-host

in FragmentTabHost When Choose Tabs onActivityCreated Create Again And All Thing Refreshed And Create new

How can Fix this ? to dont Create Again ?

**What Is Different Of Fragment LifeCycle In ViewPager And FragmentTabHost ?**

[image]

**Why FragmentShop Create Again ?**

**FragmentShop**

```
public class FragmentShop extends Fragment { 



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shop, null);
    return layout;
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    lstShop = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lstShop);
    lytPrgBar = (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.lytShopprogressBar);

    btnFloatAndswipeRefresh();
    sendAndGetDataWithListener();
    showDotedAnimate();
    AnimateBtnFloatOnListScroll();
}
```

**FragmentTabHost**

**FragmentMarket**

```
public class FragmentMarket extends Fragment {

 FragmentTabHost mTabHost;


public static Fragment instance() {
    Fragment fragment = new FragmentMarket();
    return fragment;
}





@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_market, container, false);

    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) rootView.findViewById(R.id.market_tabhost);
    mTabHost.setBackgroundResource(R.color.BlueLight);
    mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.market_realtabcontent);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("sales").setIndicator("خرید و فروش"), FragmentSales.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("estate").setIndicator("مشاوران املاک"), FragmentEstate.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("shop").setIndicator("معرفی بازار"), FragmentShop.class, null);

    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getBackground().setColorFilter(R.color.BlueDark, Mode.MULTIPLY);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getBackground().setColorFilter(R.color.BlueDark, Mode.MULTIPLY);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getBackground().setColorFilter(R.color.BlueDark, Mode.MULTIPLY);
    return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);



   }
 }
```

**About Fragment instance() :
this Method Just Create Page For ViewPager Here Is Adapter :**

```
public class AdapterViewPager extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public AdapterViewPager(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);

}


@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "مارکت";
        case 1:
            return "مجله امروز";
        case 2:
            return "رویدادها";
        case 3:
            return "آخرین اخبار";
        case 4:
            return "دانش آموزان برتر";
        case 5:
            return "قرعه کشی و جایزه";
        case 6:
            return "زیبایی و زشتی های شهر";
        case 7:
            return "حمایت";
        default:
            return "آخرین اخبار";
    }
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return FragmentMarket.instance();
        case 1:
            return FragmentMag.instance();
        case 2:
            return FragmentEvents.instance();
        case 3:
            return FragmentNews.instance();
        case 4:
            return FragmentStudent.instance();
        case 5:
            return FragmentReward.instance();
        case 6:
            return FragmentGoodBad.instance();
        case 7:
            return FragmentSupport.instance();
        default:
            return FragmentNews.instance();
    }
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 8;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally  Solution :

Here is Fragment LifeCycle :
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating

After onDestroyView All Your View Destroy But Not Your Variable

I just Do This in FragmentShop

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        lstSales = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lstSales);
        lytPrgBar = (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.lytSalesprogressBar);
        btnFloatAndswipeRefresh();
        showDotedAnimate();
        AnimateBtnFloatOnListScroll();
        if (salesTitle.isEmpty()) {
            sendAndGetDataWithListener();
        } else {
            arrayStructList.clear();
            salesDatalistener.onDataRecivce();
        }
    }
```

So You Just Need Create All View Again And Set Parameter And Don`t Get New Data And I Just Have ListView And Floating Button

This Can Help But Not For Me: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/fragment-state-saving-best-practices/en

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
        public FragmentMarket getTestFragment() {
            if (marketFragment == null) {
                marketFragment = new FragmentMarket ();
            }

            return  marketFragment; 
       }
```

Comment: TNX @};- , But Did not Work